# IllegalMonitorStateException when notifying threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program that simulates Gates to a ship. They run in threads. The idea is to let them run and pause during a random moment in the run method to simulate persons passing. This is done by all threads, meanwhile the main thread is waiting for notification and checking if the ship is getting full when notified by the threads that they added a person passing through the gate the main thread checks again if the ship is full. The program has three classes:

A counter:

```
    public class Counter {
        private int currentValue[];
        private int maxValue;

        public Counter(int[] nrOfPeople, int max) {
            currentValue = nrOfPeople;
            currentValue[0] = 0;
            maxValue = max; 
        }

        public synchronized void addPersons(int nr_p) {
            currentValue[0] += nr_p;
        }

        public synchronized int getValue() {
            return currentValue[0];
        }

        public synchronized boolean isFull() {
            if(currentValue[0] < maxValue)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

A Gate Class:

```
    public abstract class Gate implements Runnable {
        int nrOfPassengers;
        int gatenr;
        int gatesize;
        Counter c;
        private Thread t;
        private Random r;
        private boolean blocked; /* suspends people from passing */

        public Gate(Counter c, int nr) {
            this.c = c;
            gatenr = nr;
            this.open();
            r = new Random();
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        public void setGatesize(int size) {
            gatesize = size;
        }

        public void close() {
            blocked = true;
        }

        public void open() {
            blocked = false;
        }

        public int getNoOfPassangers() {
            return nrOfPassengers;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return gatenr;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!blocked) {
                int waitTime = (r.nextInt(5) + 1) * 1000; /* between 1-5 seconds */
                System.out.println("Person-Gate " + gatenr + ": adding one to " + c.getValue());
                try {
                    /* bigger throughput => amount can vary */
                    if(gatesize > 1) {
                        int persons = r.nextInt(gatesize)+1;
                        c.addPersons(persons);
                        nrOfPassengers += persons;
                    } else {
                        c.addPersons(1);
                        nrOfPassengers++;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Person-Gate " + gatenr + ": was interrupted adding person");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Person-Gate " + gatenr + ": added one to " + c.getValue());
                t.notify();
            }
        }

        public void join() {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And a Simulator that runs the main method:

```
    /*
     * This class simulates cars and persons- entering a ferry.
     */
    public class Simulator {

        public static final int MAX = 30;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int nrOfPeople[] = new int[1]; /* array of size one for keeping count */
            ArrayList<Gate> gates = new ArrayList<Gate>();
            Counter counter = new Counter(nrOfPeople, MAX);
            Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();

            /* adding 3 person-gates */
            for(int i=1; i<4; i++) {
                gates.add(new PersonGate(counter, i));
            }

            /* let all gates work as long as passengers is under MAX */
            while(!counter.isFull()) { 
                try {
                    mainThread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Announcement: Ship is full!");

            /* wait for child threads to finish */
            for(Gate g: gates) {
                g.close();
                try {
                    g.join();
                } catch (Exception e) { /* InterruptedException */
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(g.getNoOfPassangers() + " passed through gate nr " + g.getId());
                System.out.println(counter.getValue() + " has passed in total");
            }

        }
    }
```

Im getting a error

```
Person-Gate 1: adding one to 0
Person-Gate 2: adding one to 1
Person-Gate 3: adding one to 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at Simulator.main(Simulator.java:24)
Person-Gate 3: added one to 3Exception in thread "Thread-3"
```

Does anyone now whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `wait` and `notify/notifyAll` from within `synchronized` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You must own the monitor of the object on which you call wait or notify. Meaning, you must be in a synchonize-Block, like

```
synchronized( objectUsedAsSynchronizer) {
    while ( mustStillWait) {
        objectUsedAsSynchronizer.wait();
    }
}
```

This has been the subject of many other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20IllegalMonitorStateException%20wait%20notify).

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand the lock-part?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Also consider using some higher-level concurrency classes in java.util.concurrent. Or check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

```
 t.notify();
```

You are notifying wrong monitor. This exception occurs, when you do not wrap  monitor object with `synchronize` section. However, objects which you are using for notify and for wait methods are different. Create `new Object()` monitor and pass it to the constructor of Gate.

Also you can take a look at `CountDownLatch`, it does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could that monitor object be the counter instance of the Counter class?

Comment: any object can be the monitor, but you must be sure to use the same object for all threads using it.